# Finding the highest number in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I wrote a simple code to return the highest number in an array, i tried that with String array and it works fine but now i trying it with int array and it just returns -1 as default value

```
     private static int highestNum(int[] arr) {
    int high = arr[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > high) {
            high = arr[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(high);
    return high;
}
```

Am i missing something here? thank you

Comment: This code doesn't really make any sense - you should be comparing `arr[i]` to `high`, no?

Comment: yes thats the purpose of arr[i+1] @esqew

Comment: @valik But `arr[i+1]` is not the highest value found so far, so why would comparing to it be useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `high` is only updated if the the next element in the array is greater than the current value of the array in the `for` loop.

So, either:

```
if (arr[i] > high) {
   high = arr[i];
}
```

Or, I think clearer

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
  high = Math.max(high, arr[i]);
}
```

You want to update `high` when the value of the current element is greater than the previously found highest value.

Comment: i just updated my answer look above it still doesnt work

Comment: Sorry, I have a typo because I copied the code. It needs to be to `arr.length`.

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 implementation of getting highestNum from array.

```
   private static int highestNum(int[] arr) {
        OptionalInt max = IntStream.of(arr == null ? new int[] {}: arr).max();
        return (max.isPresent() ? max.getAsInt() : -1 ); // -1 assuming default 
   }
```